# Views: Filter if Value of a field equals logged in user display name?

Tags: 7, views

How to do I create a filter on my view that filters based on the value of one field being equal to the name of the currently logged in user? The field is static.

Comment: Can you describe the question little bit more. What i understood you want to show a list of records/record based on user login.

Comment: As per my assumption I believe you can achieve using contextual filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use contextual filter, as suggested by [DRUPWAY in his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228186/views-filter-if-value-of-a-field-equals-logged-in-user-display-name/228202#comment279228_228186).

1. Add a new contextual filter
2. Select the field to use
3. For *When the filter value is NOT in the URL*, select *Provide value*, and then *PHP code* for *Type*
4. In *PHP contextual filter code*, enter the following code

   ```php
   global $user;
   return $user->name;
   ```

> [image: screenshot]

For the user ID, it would be simpler: In step 3, you would select *User ID from logged in user*.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In view Relationships add "author" then in FILTER CRITERIA Add (User: Current) and select (yes) in "Is the logged in user"..

Comment: Hi @a.alshamiri, please try not to provide one-sentence answers. If possible provide a step-by-step guide with screenshots of each step, or of the final configuration screen. Thanks!

Comment: But the field I want to match isn't author.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 you can just use the module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_value